clacking in engine
2014 FR-S car engine has clacking noise ( not a tapping) 142K miles. hear it mostly when RPM hits 2500 even stationary. similar question asked by another person on here in 2023 --no answer

A lazy cam 'follower' maybe?  A cam follower that's not quite returning hard/immediate against the cam lobe when in movement can cause engine misfires or rough engine vehicle performance.
This will come out like jolts or judders if it's particularly bad.  If it's not so bad then it comes out like a slap/clack noise as the cam and follower hit each other a little (instead of being firmly constantly pressed against each other by the follower spring).
FYI - Cam followers activate the valve train. They turn the camshaft rotating motion into the vertical up/down action necessary to open and shut the piston valves for letting in air and fuel and managing exhaust at the right moments.
Hope that helps.
